# Searching text for a string

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, regex, search

This is my current code:

```
def search(word,source):
    places = []
    for x in range(0,len(source)):
        if source[x] == word[0]:
            if source[x:x+len(word)] == word:
                places.append(x)
    return places
```

How would I optimize this without using regular expressions?

Comment: I would also use yield so you can avoid creating a list and execute the appropriate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `timeit` to time the function running over 1000 iterations, as follows:

```
import timeit

def search(word=None,source=None):
    word = "is"
    source = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
    places = []
    for x in range(0, len(source)):
        if source[x] == word[0]:
            if source[x:x + len(word)] == word:
                places.append(x)
    return places

print timeit.timeit(search, number=1000)
```

This code gives us the following results (over 4 runs):

```
0.259000062943
0.12299990654
0.174999952316
0.0520000457764
```

So, we'll use that as our baseline for improvement (further runs stay constant around .052/1000).

Let's grab the low hanging fruit - caching the `len` calls:

```
import timeit

def search(word=None,source=None):
    word = "is"
    source = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
    places = []
    len_word = len(word)
    len_source = len(source)
    for x in range(0, len_source):
        if source[x] == word[0]:
            if source[x:x + len_word] == word:
                places.append(x)
    return places

print timeit.timeit(search, number=1000)
```

Improvement:

```
0.0519998493195
0.047000169754
0.0499999523163
0.0490000247955
```

Now, what happens if we get rid of `places` and just return once we find the string, as follows:

```
import timeit

def search(word=None,source=None):
    word = "is"
    source = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
    len_word = len(word)
    len_source = len(source)
    for x in range(0, len_source):
        if source[x] == word[0]:
            if source[x:x + len_word] == word:
                return x

print timeit.timeit(search, number=1000)
```

Well, this happened:

```
0.0349998474121
0.0299999713898
0.0279998779297
0.0279998779297
```

Nice! But wait, there's more! We can just use Python built ins:

```
import timeit

def search(word=None,source=None):
    word = "is"
    source = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
    return source.lower().find(word.lower())

print timeit.timeit(search, number=1000)
```

to halve the time it took us with the brute force approach:

```
0.0140001773834
0.0149999599457
0.0120000839233
0.0110000114441
```

These are the two final products, one brute force, and one using built ins, and both return the same `int` value when a word is found:

```
def search(word,source):
    len_word = len(word)
    len_source = len(source)
    for x in range(0, len_source):
        if source[x] == word[0]:
            if source[x:x + len_word] == word:
                return x

def search(word,source):
    return source.lower().find(word.lower())
```

**::EDIT::**

In regards to the comment (not same as OPs code), turn the function into an iterator rather than returning a list. This will give you the speed boost of the prior code, and still give you all the places of occurrence:

```
def search(word,source):
    len_word = len(word)
    len_source = len(source)
    for x in range(0, len_source):
        if source[x] == word[0]:
            if source[x:x + len_word] == word:
                yield x

for occurrence in search():
    print occurrence
```

**EDIT:::**

Getting rid of `if source[x] == word[0]` also gives us a nice speedup:

```
def search(word,source):
    len_word = len(word)
    len_source = len(source)
    for x in range(0, len_source):
        if source[x:x + len_word] == word:
                yield x
```

**EDIT:::**

Another quick win, caching the first chars:

```
def search(word,source):
    places = []
    len_word = len(word)
    len_source = len(source)
    first_char = word[0]
    for x in range(0, len_source):
        if source[x] == first_char:
            if source[x:x + len_word] == word:
                places.append(x)
    return places
```

Comment: Just returning the first match is **not** the same as the OP's code - although it does give a nice speed-up! Also, `len(source)` is only calculated once either way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good catch! I've edited my answer to reflect your comment and a solution that maintains the speed up, although it converts the function into a generator so a loop is needed externally.

Comment: Strangely enough, I added back the places and append, but this algorithm is now significantly slower. What is wrong?

Comment: @LiamSchumm there is overhead involved in a generator - the advantage is in not building the whole list at once (space saving), but if you want the whole list it will likely not be faster than a list comprehension (and if you do want to do it iteratively, look into `itertools`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe In which case, my code with `append()` compares in time to your code with `enumerate()`: http://repl.it/4rh - both hovering around `0.45` per 10k iterations.

Comment: @LiamSchumm Made an edit to cache the first_char, which brings my `append()` func to faster than jonrsharpe's `enumerate()` func (0.38 vs 0.45 / 10k)

Comment: Wrapping a list comprehension around your generator (the last snippet in your answer) I get 12.5s for `number=10,000`, midway between the OP's original code and my version. Note also that your code ignores its arguments, making testing difficult - I modified to change this.

Comment: @johnrsharpe Thank you for the information, I will be using this for large strings.

Comment: With your most recent edit, I get 10.5s, basically the same as my `search2`. Again your function should check e.g. `if word is None`, otherwise there's no point defining the parameters.

Comment: The argument ignore was for my testing purposes. Will remove them from answer (they shouldn't have been pasted in there).

Comment: You can substract `len_word` from `len_source` for the loop.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), we can make changes and see how it affects the speed. Baseline:

```
>>> def search1(word,source):
    places = []
    for x in range(0,len(source)):
        if source[x] == word[0]:
            if source[x:x+len(word)] == word:
                places.append(x)
    return places

>>> timeit.timeit("search1(word, source)", 
                  setup="from __main__ import search1, search2, search3; import re; word, source = 'foo', 'foobarbaz'*1000", 
                  number=10000)
15.60436644058882
```

---

Note the following:

- You calculate `word[0]` and `len(word)` on every loop, these can be factored out;
- A list comprehension is generally faster than `for` looping and `append`ing; and
- `enumerate` allows you to get the index and character from `source` simultaneously.

With those in mind:

```
>>> def search2(word, source):
    """Find every index in source at which word starts."""
    firstchar = word[0]
    wordlen = len(word)
    return [index for index, char in enumerate(source) 
            if firstchar == char and word == source[index:index+wordlen]]

>>> timeit.timeit("search2(word, source)", 
                  setup="from __main__ import search1, search2, search3; import re; word, source = 'foo', 'foobarbaz'*1000", 
                  number=10000)
9.99040215947457
```

I have also added a [docstring](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to explain what the function does.

---

However, if you really want efficiency (and readability, for that matter), ignoring regular expressions is a bad move:

```
>>> def search3(word, source):
    """Find every index in source at which word starts."""
    return [m.start() for m in re.finditer(word, source)]

>>> timeit.timeit("search3(word, source)", 
                  setup="from __main__ import search1, search2, search3; import re; word, source = 'foo', 'foobarbaz'*1000", 
                  number=10000)
2.1652778798459167
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an inefficient way to do that without regex. But not very different from your version.

```
>>> string = "test test test test"
>>> [i for i in range(len(string)) if string.startswith('test', i)]
[0, 5, 10, 15]
```

What's the problem in using regex? It's a built-in module. I would use regex because it's often the most efficient way to do more complex things like unpredictable lengths of inputs. Also regarding runtime. For example right now you are also searching for overlapping solutions. Do you want that? If you will search for long words and you don't want to find overlapping solutions you can skip a lot of iterations. Regex will do that automatically.

```
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer('test', 'test test test test')]
[0, 5, 10, 15]
```

If you want to find overlapping matches, [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will do that:

```
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer('(?=tt)', 'ttt')]
[0, 1]
```

Also look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python).

I also tried just optimize your solution and ended up with

```
>>> def search(word, source):
...     w_len = len(word)
...     for x in range(0, len(source)):
...         if source[x:x+w_len] == word:
...             yield x
...
>>> [i for i in search('foo', 'foobarbazfoobarbaz')]
[0, 9]
```